# A "throw err" error message keeps showing up

Tags: node.js, syntax-error, discord.js

Every time I have my discord bot sitting online, ever since I added a small json data base, it goes offline and shows this error in my console without being triggered from a command taking place.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Prince-Yami\entrydata.json: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 833
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:27)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.checkInData (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Prince-Yami\indexDATA.js:8:23)
    at Client.bot.on.msg (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Prince-Yami\index.js:47:17)
    at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
```

You see, I'm kinda new to this, so I don't fully understand what's wrong happening here wrong. I've ried to look through the files to understand the error in my code but I can't tell what's wrong exactly.

Heres my indexDATA.js file code:

```
module.exports = {
    checkInData: function(msg) {
        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        const bot = new Discord.Client();
        const PREFIX = 'sick.';
        const fs = require("fs")
        bot.entries = require('./entrydata.json')
        let args = msg.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

        switch(args[0]){
            case 'entry':
              editedmsg = msg.content.slice(17);

              bot.entries [args[1]] = {
                message: editedmsg
              }
              const configD = JSON.stringify (bot.entries, null, 4)
              fs.writeFile ("./entrydata.json", configD, err => {
                if (err) throw err;
                msg.channel.send('Entry noted');
              });
            break;
            case 'entryget':
              let _message = bot.entries[args[1]].message;
              msg.channel.send(_message);
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

And here's my entrydata.json file:

```
{
    "00000": {
        "message": "**Scene 1**"
    },
  }
```

Comment: dangling *comma* in your `json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the comma in entrydata.json:

```
{
    "00000": {
        "message": "**Scene 1**"
    }
}
```